# OpenAPI 3.x.x having different response with the change of Optional Parameters

Tags: swagger, openapi, api-documentation

I am trying to create the OAS Swagger documentation for an existing API where the response for the API is changing on the basis of Query parameter. I am struggling to document this in a developer friendly way, so need some assistance. Below is the complete scenario for your reference.

**EndPoint 1 :** /order?expand=false

```js
/order?expand=false

{
    "orderNo": "12345",
    "orderDetail": "Description of Order",
    "orderMarket": {
        "id": "UK"
    },
    "brandOrderStatus": {
        "id": "LLA"
    }
}
```

**Endpoint 2 :**  /order?expand=true

```js
{
    "orderNo": "12345",
    "orderDetail": "Description of Order",
    "orderMarket": {
        "id": "UK",
        "descr": "United Kingdom",
        "lang": "en-GB"
    },
    "brandOrderStatus": {
        "id": "LLA",
        "descr": "Some Status Description",
        "lang": "en-GB"
    }
}
```

**Endpoint 3 :** /order?expand=true&include=feature

```js
{
    "orderNo": "12345",
    "orderDetail": "Description of Order",
    "orderMarket": {
        "id": "UK",
        "descr": "United Kingdom",
        "lang": "en-GB"
    },
    "brandOrderStatus": {
        "id": "LLA",
        "descr": "Some Status Description",
        "lang": "en-GB"
    }
    "_embedded": {
        "features": [
            {
                "id": "AJS",
                "type": "FeatureType",
                "descr": "FeatureDescription",
                "prices": [
                    {
                        "type": "msrpNetPrice",
                        "amount": 0.00,
                        "currency": "GBP"
                    }
                ],
                "group": "null"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried using OneOf, but don't really think that will work in this case as the structure is changing with every optional parameter.

Any thoughts as how this can be documented in Swagger documentation ? Or any other idea to get this documented.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward solution to something like this depends on how you expect to use the OpenAPI description. If it's for documentation purposes only, you can use `examples` and define those accordingly. If you want to use it for code-gen, using `anyOf` may be the better option to define the expected payload.

Unfortunately, OpenAPI doesn't have a terrific way to document "scenarios" like this. (if I send these query params, this is the response). None of the `examples` will explicitly correspond to the `anyOf` schema representations. You need to define the entire response either with the full representation or with a `anyOf` schema design.

Here's with examples and anyOf response schemas

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.3",
  "info": {
    "title": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [],
  "paths": {
    "/order": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "stack",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/expand"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/parameters/include"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "headers": {},
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "anyOf": [
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/order"
                    },
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/orderDetail"
                    },
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/orderDetailWithFeatures"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "examples": {
                  "expand_false": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/examples/expand_false"
                  },
                  "expand_true": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/examples/expand_true"
                  },
                  "expand_with_features": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/examples/expand_with_features"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "parameters": {
      "expand": {
        "name": "expand",
        "description": "expands the response schema with more details",
        "in": "query",
        "schema": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "include": {
        "name": "include",
        "description": "expands the response schema with more details",
        "in": "query",
        "schema": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "feature"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "schemas": {
      "order": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "orderNo": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "orderDetail": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "orderMarket": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "brandOrderStatus": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "amountType": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "amount": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "currency": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "USD",
              "GBP",
              "EUR"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "lang-descType": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "lang": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "descr": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "features": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "descr": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "prices": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/amountType"
              }
            },
            "group": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "orderDetail": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/order"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "orderMarket": {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/lang-descType"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "brandOrderStatus": {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/lang-descType"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "orderDetailWithFeatures": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/orderDetail"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "_embedded": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "features": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/features"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "examples": {
      "expand_false": {
        "value": {
          "orderNo": "12345",
          "orderDetail": "Description of Order",
          "orderMarket": {
            "id": "UK"
          },
          "brandOrderStatus": {
            "id": "LLA"
          }
        }
      },
      "expand_true": {
        "value": {
          "orderNo": "12345",
          "orderDetail": "Description of Order",
          "orderMarket": {
            "id": "UK",
            "descr": "United Kingdom",
            "lang": "en-GB"
          },
          "brandOrderStatus": {
            "id": "LLA",
            "descr": "Some Status Description",
            "lang": "en-GB"
          }
        }
      },
      "expand_with_features": {
        "value": {
          "orderNo": "12345",
          "orderDetail": "Description of Order",
          "orderMarket": {
            "id": "UK",
            "descr": "United Kingdom",
            "lang": "en-GB"
          },
          "brandOrderStatus": {
            "id": "LLA",
            "descr": "Some Status Description",
            "lang": "en-GB"
          },
          "_embedded": {
            "features": [
              {
                "id": "AJS",
                "type": "FeatureType",
                "descr": "FeatureDescription",
                "prices": [
                  {
                    "type": "msrpNetPrice",
                    "amount": 0.00,
                    "currency": "GBP"
                  }
                ],
                "group": "null"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer to use `anyOf` rather than `oneOf` because all of the payload representations are a subset of the larger `withFeatures` payload, thus using `oneOf` doesn't pass validation because a `oneOf` payload must only pass validation against one schema definition with this keyword.