# Openapi specification anyOf with discriminator

Tags: openapi

I try to understand in which cases one might use anyOf in conjunction with a discriminator in an openapi specification. As a discriminator can only have one type (i.e. point to one schema), why should one use anyOf instead of oneOf? The only reason I could think of is, if at least one schema is a subset of another schema and therefore a response or request might be valid against more than one schema. So this is more a technical reason than semantics or what did I miss?

Or another question: What would you expect from a generator tool which creates DTO's from the components in the schema section in such a case? Assuming the DTO already provides a fold method, which one can register a functions for each possible schema, e.g. if one has a `Dog` and a `Cat` in an anyOf composition with a discriminator.

Would the following (Java) method be a reasonable outcome of the generator?

```
public <T> T fold(Function<DogDto, T> onDog, Function<CatDto, T> onCat);
```

One can register a function to handle the Dog case and the Cat case and based on the discriminator, the correct function will get executed. Altough it is an anyOf composition and depending on the schema a Dog might be valid too in case a Cat was actually sent, only the Cat function gets executed if the discriminator has type Cat.

Without a discriminator, the fold method will look like this:

```
public <T> List<T> fold(Function<DogDto, T> onDog, Function<CatDto, T> onCat);
```

Every function gets executed for which the request/response was valid.

Comment: here's an example of using `anyOf` where subschemas are used. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77002583/8564731

Comment: @JeremyFiel Thank you! Although you didn't use a discriminator, I think oneOf would be semantically more correct in that case but cannot be used as `orderDetail` and `orderDetailWithFeatures` will not be valid cause the response will be also valid against `order` too.

Comment: I started with oneOf but you can see my comment where I changed it to anyOf because of that reason.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't saw your comment there. I will add another question concerning code generation in such a case.